# Project Euler 4 Python with Dictionary that adds Digits to Answers

Tags: python, list, dictionary, math

I manage to solve the 4th problem of Project Euler & want to take it a step further by not only finding the answer but assigning the corresponding multiplying 3-digits to the answer too. I basically want to assign the corresponding multiples to the palindrome i.e. {palindrome: digit1 digit2}. that is digit1*digit2=palindrome.

For those of you who have not done the Project Euler, here is the question:

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99. Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

```
ns = str(n)
ns_list = []
ns_list_to_int = []
#outside for loop with first 3-digit 'num' and inside loop with second 3-digit 'i'
for num in range (100,1000):
    for i in range(100,1000):
        n = i*num

#need to convert to string & check if reverse of string == string, if so append to list
        ns = str(n)
        if ns[::-1] == ns:
            ns_list.append({ns:str(i) + ' 'str(num) })

#recreate new list with integers to sort
for i in ns_list:
    ns_list_to_int.append(int(i))

#sort in descending order and call the first number 
ns_list_to_int = sorted(stuffs, key=int, reverse=True)
ns_list_to_int[0]
```

tried to get it with ns_list.append({ns:str(i) + ' 'str(num) }) but it doesn't seem to work. Also, not sure how then I would be able to sort it if it is a dictionary.

Comment: You have explained what you want to do, but I see no question. What exactly are you asking us? Is there something wrong with your code?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: The first paragraph indicates that they want to know not only the palindrome, but the numbers that multiplied to produce it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I know that. I was encouraging the questioner to ask a good question--in particular, to be specific as to what is being asked and what is wrong with the attempted code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the lack of clarity. I have made the suggested changes & hope that adds more clarity to the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple approach is to replace `ns_list` with a `dict`, then replace `ns_list.append(ns)` with `ns_dict[num, i] = ns`.

Alternatively, to keep the palindromes as the top level iterable component, you can store all the pairs that produced a particular palindrome in a `list`, using `collections.defaultdict(list)` to simplify the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ns_dict = defaultdict(list)

#outside for loop with first 3-digit 'num' and inside loop with second 3-digit 'i'
for num in range(100,1000):
    for i in range(100,1000):
        n = i*num
        ns = str(n)
        if ns[::-1] == ns:
            ns_dict[ns].append((num, i))
```

Now when you iterate `ns_dict`, you can see all the pairs you checked that produced that palindrome:

```
ns_list_with_factors = sorted(ns_dict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]), reverse=True)
print(ns_list_with_factors[0])  # Displays both number and the pairs that produced it

for ns, pairs in ns_dict.items():
    ...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I tried running the first code but I am getting this error:
---> 11             ns_dict[ns].append((num, i))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @james: Sorry, stupid mistype. Fixing. I said `defaultdict(list)` in the text, then typed it in the code as `defaultdict(int)`. It should be `defaultdict(list)` everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for and more

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending just the product (your variable ns), you could append a tuple/list/object which contains not only the palindromic number but also the two multiples.

Then all you need to change further down is the sorting function.

Quick and dirty example:

```
ns_list = []
ns_list_to_int = []
#outside for loop with first 3-digit 'num' and inside loop with second 3-digit 'i'
for num in range (100,1000):
    for i in range(100,1000):
        n = i*num

#need to convert to string & check if reverse of string == string, if so append to list
        ns = str(n)
        if ns[::-1] == ns:
            pint = int(ns) # convert palindrome to int
            t = (i,num,pint) # all the info you need for later
            ns_list.append(t)


#sort in descending order and call the first number
ns_list_to_int = sorted(ns_list, key=lambda x:x[2], reverse=True) # sorting by the palindrome
ns_list_to_int[0]
```

Comment: didn't know I could do that with tuples. Thanks!